# How does the distinction between association and causation affect the interpretation of linear models?

Tags: correlation, linear-model, interpretation, endogeneity, causality

Lurking variables probably have something to do with this. I'm just trying to figure out how their difference can affect a linear model.

Answer (score 2):

The (potentially causal) interpretation of your model doesn't come from the model itself.  It comes from the design / setup of your study.  Causality can primarily be inferred from your model when you ran a true experiment.  There are various methods for attempting to infer causality with observational data (e.g., instrumental variables, difference-in-differences, propensity scores, etc.), but they all require additional assumptions and are not as strong as experiments in general.  If you don't have a true experiment, it is safest to always assume your model estimates a marginal association only.

Omitted / lurking variables affect this when they are correlated with $X$ variables in your model and with your response ($Y$) variable.  In that case, they bias your estimates such that a variable could appear causal when it actually isn't.  To understand this better, it may help to read my answer here: [Estimating $b_1x_1+b_2x_2$ instead of $b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58712/7290).

Comment: I'm a little confused by the link you posted. Are you saying that correlation affects the error? So if I have a variable that is correlated then I have a bias in the model? Sorry, I'm a bit confused...

Comment: @Carla, yes that's the idea. If there is a variable x3 that is correlated w/ both another x variable (x2) & is correlated w/ y, then there can be problems. Eg, x2 can be causally unrelated to Y, but will look like it causes Y.