# Model causality: graphical models and PCA

Tags: self-study, pca, graphical-model

If we build a graphical model (DAG) we (may) interpret the arrows as causal dependences.

If we build a graphical model based on the variables returned by principal component analysis (PCA) we should obtain a totally disconnected graph (assuming normality). We could interpret this as the variables given by the principal components having no causal dependency and being attributed to different (latent) causes.

How are these interpretations of the data compatible ? Is the concept of causality dependent on the set of variables chosen as a bases?

ps: for easiness of interpetation we may suppose that all variables have the same unit of measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The principal components you obtain are orthogonal (uncorrelated) among themselves **by definition** (of PCA), which is already not a great start if you want to assume some kind of dependence among them.
2. Besides that, they do not carry a natural meaning from the perspective of your domain of study (only statistical) except the one you give them.

Maybe you can include principal components in a DAG, but in practice you will have to make several assumptions and in general I really do not think is a good idea (I am very much open to counterexamples).
On the other hand, you could infer relationships (correlation, non causation) among the original variables computing the correlation coefficient between them and the principal components. From the interpretation of these correlations potentially you could add new nodes (your principal components) in your original DAG as latent variable with arrows into the variables they mostly correlate with.

To answer this part of the question:

> Is the concept of causality dependent on the set of variables chosen
> as a bases?

The concept of causality depends mainly on you and your situation. Causal inference can be very useful, but I think its reasoning is not unique (except in some straightforward cases). As follows a partial and succint explanation of why (in my opinion):

**First: Can I find a DAG for all situations?** The concept of causality is always highly dependable on the researcher knowledge and the data that are available. On top of these two things, building a DAG is dependent on your research question. Unless you are looking into a deterministic problem (for example in physics), you cannot build a "complete" DAG the stands in any possible situation (any research question) involving these variables.

The book [What If](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/) by Hernan and Robins is a simple introduction* to the DAGs world using a perspective from structural causal inference, where you can find some not too complicated mathematical proofs of their reasoning.
**Second: using my own DAG.** The theoretical framework described in the book provides you with some ready-made statistical tools to investigate your data based on the DAG you define, but eventually even in this case I almost always end up using different statistical tools (such as PCA) to back up my reasoning and get new insights.

Just so you know, this relationship between correlations and orthogonality is not widely accepted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171324/what-is-the-relationship-between-orthogonal-correlation-and-independence)

*There are other views and styles you might like better, but in this book they really take it slow and eventually you get quick comprehensive picture on several topics. On the other hand, if you are more machine learning oriented I recommend [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.15475).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (+1) and for the references. I will wait a couple of days to see if there are other contributions and if not I will accept your answer. In the meanwhile I will  read the first chapter of the book you suggested ;). Ah slow is good :D

Comment: Great! I really hope it helps. Consider that other causal inference source use much more the `do` calculus, but in that book is never used. Not an essential info honestly, but just to inform you.

Comment: "so there can be no arrows from one to another" - why would this be true? Variables can be orthogonal / not correlated, yet still be causally related, cf. the discussion linked to in my answer. Missing edges in causal DAGs imply "no direct causal effect", which is distinct from "not correlated".

Comment: Yes, I modified the answer so hopefully now is also clearer. However, the point is that we are talking about Principal Components, not any "real" variables, so in this case uncorrelation has a very strong importance per se (in my opinion).

Comment: Hmm... but the PCs are just linear combinations of the original ("real") variables, and if those follow a complex causal structure then so will the PCs, no? Sure, you can *assume* that these particular linear recombinations are not causally related, but that seems to me like the counterpart to assuming that spurious correlations indicate causality.

Answer (score 3):

PCA makes no statements about causality; it merely identifies (linearly) uncorrelated factors of variation. [That two variables are (linearly) uncorrelated does *not* imply that they cannot be causally related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221936/131402), so if you want your graphical model to represent causality, then you basically cannot conclude anything about the presence or absence of edges from a PCA.

--

Let us consider a simple example. You have two variables, $A$ and $B$. $A$ follows a standard normal distribution, and $B$ is *caused* by $A$ following $B:=A+\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ follows another standard-normal distribution. Thus, B is also normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 2, and $A$ and $B$ together are jointly normally distributed, as (I understand) you assumed in your question. If one intervenes on $A$, that will change $B$, but if one intervenes on $B$, that will not change $A$.

Firstly, notice that purely from observations of the joint distribution of $A$ and $B$, it is impossible to conclude anything about their causal relationship! $A$ could be causing $B$ (as we assume it is), $B$ could be causing $A$, or both could be caused by a common confounder. (Also see [the nice example on Jonas Peters' homepage](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Epeters/) in this regard.)

Now you perform a PCA, which will give you the principal vectors $PV_1=(1, 1)/\sqrt{2}$ and $PV_2=(1,-1)/\sqrt{2}$, associated with the principal components $PC_1=A+B$ and $PC_2=A-B$. The correct causal diagram would now be that both $PC_1$ and $PC_2$ are caused by both $A$ and $B$, which follow whatever causal relationship was true for them in the first place. In essence, it seems to me that the principal components will always be descendants of shared confounders, namely all the original variables.

--

Inferring any kind of causal relationships from purely observational data is an extremely hard task and [generally](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3400/131402) [impossible](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127354/131402) [without](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/493211/131402) imposing additional assumptions ("I know for a fact that $B$ *cannot* cause $A$, and I also know for a fact that there cannot be any third thing influencing both of them."). For a great overview on the assumptions one can make to achieve this, I recommend [Jonas Peters' book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262037310/) (PDF available for free under the link). It is, however, very much a topic of [current research](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9363924) and essentially unsolved. In this regard, I also found the historical struggle to prove something as "obvious" as that smoking causes cancer quite instructive. ([[1]](https://ete-online.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1742-7622-3-1), [[2]](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Efl35/teaching/440-19F/Tutorial_PlusDS.pdf), [[3]](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/data_statistics/sgr/2004/pdfs/chapter1.pdf), [[4]](https://www.acsh.org/news/2017/10/31/acsh-explains-hills-criteria-determining-causality-correlation-12013))

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. This is an important point I think. Indeed I think the PC algorithm for DAG construction starts from tests of uncorrelation (and partial uncorrelation) to remove edges. This is indeed just a proxy of independence (and partial independence). So here come many questions:

Comment: (1) do we need an algorithm testing really independence instead of uncorrelation to to a DAG on PCA variables? (2) if the answer to question (1) is positive, since in the same system one can build a DAG with original variables already at the level of the PC algorithm, this means that a DAG based on PCA variables is probing some different causal relation than the DAG based on the original variables?

Comment: (3) In my original question trying to circumvent this issue I wrote the magic word "normality". For normal variables "uncorrelation -> independence", as a well known fact. Does the OP make more sense to you in this setting?

Comment: Mmm... this answer is useful but addresses only a part of the question. It would need more discussion and follow up.

Comment: I tried to clarify my argument with an example. I honestly do not know the "PC algorithm for DAG construction" and could not immediately find something when searching for it; can you point me to a reference where it is discussed?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I will read your answer and see if it addresses the questions. For the moment I send you somr links https://github.com/huawei-noah/trustworthyAI/tree/master/gcastle

Comment: https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume8/kalisch07a/kalisch07a.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! From a brief skim, I notice that a) the PC algorithm has nothing to do with PCA?, b) as the authors note, it can only identify an "equivalence class of DAGs with corresponding distribution P. Even when having infinitely many observations, we cannot distinguish among the different DAGs of an equivalence class." - in other words, it cannot be used to make inferences about causality. That's basically also what I illustrate in my example above. (Happy to be corrected if I am misunderstanding something!)

Comment: Thanks I need some time to review your example but +1 because I think your answer is useful and instructive

Comment: Regarding PCA yes that is a generic algorithm for DAG learning. My question concerns about the choice of variables on which to build a graph. PCA is an example about variables which are difficult to interpret, like a limiting example. I am interested yo understand if it makes sense to use PCA to build a DAG but also what type of variables make sense in general to use to build a DAG

Comment: Regarding your other comment, I think that indeed in some situations you cannot determine what is the cause and what an effect but it depends on the setting. There are (not rare) situations in which the data structure univocally identifies the orientation of some or every of the arrows in a causal dag. In this situations something can be suggested about causality. That is the 'orientation' step in the pca algorithm in the github repo.

Comment: anyway I am trying to learn these things that is why I make questions :)

Comment: (Sorry from the phone sometimes I am writing pc instead of pca and vite versa)

Comment: @Thomas Regarding "There are (not rare) situations in which the data structure univocally identifies the orientation of some or every of the arrows in a causal dag." - at least to my understanding, this is really not true, *unless* you have additional external knowledge /constraints that you can impose on the identification method. Even if $A$ looks like it's clearly causing $B$, that could always be due to some third variable that is causing both of them. (Hence e.g. the tremendous struggles to conclusively show something as "obvious" as that smoking causes cancer.)

Comment: Yes also up to my understanding you are right. I think somewhere I read indeed that you must have as an hypothesis that all the relevant variables are included in the modelling otherwise the arrows that you obtain would not have a causal meaning. Adding the forgotten variables the arrows may change. This is probably an example of thr external knowledge you are referring to. (and even of you have included all variables there are situations in which you cannot drive conclusions from the data)

Comment: Anyway sorry for not having the time that I would like to dedicate to study your example today. I plan to do it soon. Just to say I am not overlooking it and I am interested in understanding it well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143000/discussion-between-thomas-and-eike-p).