# Why an interaction stops being significant when adding more variables?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, modeling, interaction, ordinal-data

I have a model with two variables, and the interaction between them is significant, 0.041. When adding 9 more variables to the model (from which just two are significant), the previous interaction between the two first variables is not significant anymore. Why can this happen?

Comment: Well, all sorts of things can happen, but when adding 7 more predictors, they are so effective that they explain alone what was previously explained by the interaction?

Comment: Have you checked out this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52067/does-adding-more-variables-into-a-multivariable-regression-change-coefficients-o)? What is the model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model)